# Changing order/color of the items - Legend ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to link the new order of the items of my legend to certain colors.
However, everytime I try something, I have to chose either between getting the order of the items as I want it or chosing the colors I want.

Here are the codes I used (they are both the exact same except for the part in bold that is the last line):
1). Colors:

```
TPC_T2<-ggplot(T2_M4M1, aes(x=Temperature, y=mm_per_day, colour=Population, group=Population)) 
 + geom_line() 
 + geom_point() 
 + theme(panel.background =element_rect(fill="white", colour="lightgrey")) 
 **+ scale_color_manual(values=c("forestgreen", "royalblue","lightcoral"))**
```

2). Order:

```
TPC_T2<-ggplot(T2_M4M1, aes(x=Temperature, y=mm_per_day, colour=Population, group=Population)) 
 + geom_line() 
 + geom_point()  
 + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="white",colour="lightgrey"))  
 **+scale_colour_discrete(breaks=c("SAR~200m","MOR~900m","PAC~1600m"))**
```

I tried to add these two lines (in bold) in the same code but it doesn't work. I also tried to do it like this:

```
+ scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("SAR~200m","MOR~900m","PAC~1600m"), values=c("royalblue", "forestgreen", "lightcoral"))
```

But it doesn't work neither.

I would like to have the order by altitude and with that colors :
SAR~200m in red
MOR~900m in green 
PAC~1600m in blue

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Please, provide a sample of your data.

Comment: Try the following 2 commands: First, set the order of your factor levels. `T2_M4M1$Population = factor(as.character(T2_M4M1$Population), levels=c("SAR~200m","MOR~900m","PAC~1600m"))`. Then used a named vector of colors with a manual scale. `scale_colour_manual(values=c("SAR~200m"="royalblue", "MOR~900m"="forestgreen", "PAC~1600m"="lightcoral"))`. Notice that the name of each color matches exactly one of the levels in `Population`.

Comment: Thank you! I just found that command (that is exactly the same that the one you wrote, except for 'as.character') and it finally worked:

    T2_M4M1$Population <- factor(T2_M4M1$Population, levels = c("SAR~200m", "MOR~900m", "PAC~1600m"))    

With the scale_colour_manual vector then in my code, everything is just as I wanted it :

    + scale_color_manual(values=c("lightcoral","forestgreen", "royalblue"))